# Postgresql nested aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find the employees who have taken the maximum number of leaves in the current month.

I started with this query:

```
select MAX(TotalLeaves) as HighestLeaves 
FROM (SELECT emp_id, count(adate) as TotalLeaves 
      from attendance 
      group by emp_id) AS HIGHEST;
```

But i am facing problems in displaying the employee id and getting the result only for the current month. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show corresponding employee_id in your current query, you can sort results and get top 1 row, and you need to filter data before group to get only current month:

```
select
    emp_id, TotalLeaves
from (
    select emp_id, count(adate) as TotalLeaves 
    from attendance
    where adate >= date_trunc('month', current_date)
    group by emp_id
) as highest
order by TotalLeaves desc
limit 1;
```

Actually, you don't need to use subquery at all here:

```
select emp_id, count(adate) as TotalLeaves 
from attendance
where adate >= date_trunc('month', current_date)
group by emp_id
order by TotalLeaves desc
limit 1;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8dc0d/1)</kbd>**

Comment: I had another query too. I have two tables: Sales(invoice_id, customer_id, sales_date, total amount) AND Invoice(invoice_id, qty, price, prod_id, total_amount). How can i find the products that were not sold in last week??

Comment: @user2944346 I think it's better to ask another question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp_id, count(adate) as TotalLeaves 
  from attendance
  where adata > date_trunc('month', NOW())
  group by emp_id
  order by 2 desc limit 1
```